# Is it possible to construct build environment for cross-compiling for different target environment?

Tags: cross-compiling, package-management, build-management

In these days, I'm learning joy of open-source world. With *Homebrew* package build management system on Mac OS X. Building software for my purpose was so easy and simple.

Anyway, those package systems are designed for host system only. If I want to build a library (for an example `OpenCV`) for other system (for an example, iOS, Android or Ubuntu), is there any option?

*The *cross-compile* means compiling for target system `B` on host system `A`.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV already has ports to Android and iOS - Android port is officially released with OpenCV 2.3.1; iOS port is currently available in OpenCV trunk only.

Both ports are using cmake for cross-compiling. You can download the sources and see how this is done. Instructions for building Android port are available on [OpenCV wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android)

Answer (score 0):

See CMake project: http://www.cmake.org/

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the OP wants to *cross-compile*, which requires more than just a cross-platform build system.